# How to implement endpoint authentication without hardcoding client identifiers in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

How can I secure endpoints with authentication using for example Google Accounts or OAuth2?

Is it possible to do it at all?

I read many sample in web but not found solution which allow keep user database out of code.

Current solution for authentication is not sufficient for it - [appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-python/blob/master/helloworld_api.py).

Problem with this API is such that I need **hardcode identifiers** how to workaround it?

```
WEB_CLIENT_ID = 'replace this with your web client application ID'
ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = 'replace this with your Android client ID'
IOS_CLIENT_ID = 'replace this with your iOS client ID'
ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID

@endpoints.api(name='helloworld', version='v1',
               allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
                                   IOS_CLIENT_ID],
               audiences=[ANDROID_AUDIENCE])
class HelloWorldApi(remote.Service):
    """Helloworld API v1."""
```

I want to define allowed_client_ids dynamically with use some database not and want share API with python applications - if it possible at all. How to do it?

Comment: What about putting the client IDs in a configuration yaml or something and pull that in during runtime?

Comment: It is hardcoding in *.yaml same like in *.py. I think about 10k of client ids not about moving one id from *.py - not have problem with one at all.

Comment: Oh I actually missed what you were saying, I thought you were trying to hide stuff on the client side. What you want may not be possible in the way you're describing. Maybe this might help https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: I need to try python client to check how it works with oauth but not found good example how to do it - all demos is focus on web, android, ios what is not useful for me (or half of what is need).